# Ruby Koans about_constants.rb

Tags: ruby, constants

Making my way through the Ruby Koans after completing the first 4 chapters of Hartl's Rails tutorial. I'm stuck at the beginning of about_constants.rb

The koan is meant to be demonstrating the hierarchy of constants. Clearly I'm missing something simple here (this is the first programming learning I've done) but I can't seem to find out where I'm going wrong. Any insight is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here is the code I've been trying below:

```
Macintosh:~ rails$ irb
2.0.0p247 :001 > C = "top level"
 => "top level" 
2.0.0p247 :002 > class AboutConstants
2.0.0p247 :003?>   C = "nested"
2.0.0p247 :004?>   end
 => "nested" 
2.0.0p247 :005 > C
 => "top level" # WRONG - correct response should be "nested"
2.0.0p247 :006 > ::C
 => "top level" # CORRECT
```

For reference the top part of about_constants.rb that I am working on:

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/neo')

C = "top level"

class AboutConstants < Neo::Koan

  C = "nested"

  def test_nested_constants_may_also_be_referenced_with_relative_paths
    assert_equal __, C
  end

  def test_top_level_constants_are_referenced_by_double_colons
    assert_equal __, ::C
  end

  def test_nested_constants_are_referenced_by_their_complete_path
    assert_equal __, AboutConstants::C
    assert_equal __, ::AboutConstants::C
  end
```

Comment: Do all the assertions work? It looks to me like the assertions are nested inside the `AboutConstants` class, which would evaluate differently than the console code you posted.

Comment: I think it's the code that I'm doing wrong, do you have any suggestions as to how I should do it correctly?

Comment: Well, if by the code you mean the console code, try putting the `C` you have on line 5 into a `class AboutConstants` block, since that's what the assertions seem to be doing. Hopefully that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the constants in your irb console from a different context than the koans exercise does.

Your try:

1. You're calling the constant `C` out of the class `AboutConstants`, after you close the class definition. So the path you're calling is referencing to the constant at the same context/level as the call, it means: out of the class, so when you call `C` the interpreter will find first the outer constant `C` whose value is "top level".
2. When you called `::C` the interpreter won't find an outer level so it will return the same value "top level".

Koan exercise:

1. It calls the constant `C` from the class definition, before the class definition ends. So the interpreter will find the constant in the same context/level which is "nested".
2. Now, when `::C` is called, the interpreter will try to find the constant `C` in the next level so it will find the outer constant whose value is "top level".